# How can I programmatically check if a view's result is not empty?

Tags: views

Programmatically, How to check if view result is not empty with in custom function?
I want to check the views result is it empty or not, and then display the result. How can i do?

```
use Drupal\views\Views;
use Drupal\views\ViewExecutable;

$view = Views::getView($view_name = "My View");
$view->setTitle('Sample Title');
$view->setArguments($args = ['all']);
$view->display_handler->setOption('empty', $empty = 'No content');
$view->preExecute();

// Need to check if empty result, before render

$markup = $view->render();
```

Comment: use `$view->execute();` and `if (!empty($view->result)) { ...`

Comment: Yes, it's working fine.